# Ruby on Rails - Add Random Adjective + Noun

Tags: ruby

I am using Rails 4, and I came across [this cool gist](https://gist.github.com/afriggeri/1266756) the other day.

Any way, how would I do something similar with Rails where I can randomly choose from two arrays to generate a somewhat-unique name?

I know there are Gems for this (e.g., [Bazaar](https://github.com/raycchan/bazaar) and [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker)).  But I like the idea of using my own simple list.

Any help on how to get this started would be fabulous.

Comment: `nouns.sample` seems simple enough: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-sample. Do that twice. And no, that looks like CoffeeScript, and it looks nothing like Java.

Comment: When you ask a question, you *really* should shorten your sample data and code to the bare minimum necessary to show the problem. Anything beyond that and you distract people and discourage answers because you force potential answerers to wade through unnecessary detail. It's a case of helping us help you.

Comment: My apologies to all.  This was, in fact, a poorly worded question with ambiguous meaning and lack of clarity.  I am going on 65 hours straight of no sleep.  I am well aware of how to ask questions on SO.  But thank you for your very kind reminders and nicely worded comments.  They have been helpful in assisting me with asking future questions on this wonderful platform.  Best wishes to you all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's your haiku method rewritten in Ruby. I shortened the word lists for readability.

```
def haiku
  adjs = ["autumn", "hidden", "bitter", "misty", "silent", "empty", "dry", "dark"]
  nouns = ["waterfall", "river", "breeze", "moon", "rain", "wind", "sea", "morning"]

  [adjs.sample, nouns.sample].join('_')
end

puts haiku # returns random combination like "bitter_rain" or "empty_sea"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pick a random element from an array in ruby just use [`Array#sample`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample).

```
my_array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
my_array.sample #gives a random element of the list
```